# Location of the translation 'All [category]' in submenu

Tags: magento2, localisation

I want to find the location (or source) of the translation of the 'All [CATEGORY]' string in the submenu (All componenten in this situation):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about a submenu in the main navigation? If so the string is defined in `lib/web/mage/menu.js` on line `286`.

You can translate it by adding: `"All ",Your translation ,lib,lib/web/mage/menu.js` to your translation file.

Comment: It doesn't work, but shouldn't there be a variable involved in the translation? Like "All %s", "Alle %s","module","Magento_Catalog"

Comment: No variable needed, if you look at the source `.text($.mage.__('All ') + category);` you'll see that the `category` is defined outside of the `__()` translation function. Are you adding the translation in a theme translation file or in a module translation pack?

Comment: I am adding the translation in a theme translation file located in app > design > frontend > vendor > store > i18n > nl_NL.csv.

Comment: I see, I've got it working when using a language pack only. There are some bugs in M2 when translating strings defined in js, that might be the cause. See this issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7525